# Convert Date field's value into milliseconds

Tags: formula, formula-field, datetime

Could someone please help me with a formula to convert Date field's value into milliseconds. I need the millisecods to be calculated from 01st Jan 1970. Thanks in advance. Convert Date

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use regular subtraction, then multiply by 86400000.

## Date

```
(Date__c - DATE(1970, 1, 1)) * 86400000
```

## DateTime

```
(Date_Time__c - DATETIMEVALUE("1970-01-01 00:00:00")) * 86400000
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried the first formula with type Date, Date/Time and Time, but it gave syntax error- 'Formula result is data type (Date), incompatible with expected data type (Time). (Related field: Formula)'. It was successful with type Number. Hope that's fine.

Comment: @SalesforceLearner Yes, "time" values are a hour:minute:second type deal, not suited for millisecond display. Number is the type I would have expected you to use.